# Sql Update - Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have below query to update field sku of table o to field AutoSKU of table p. And running it give me error: "Ambiguous column name 'sku'". I also know the problem is because the engine doesn't know which sku I am talking about in the WHERE condition. But I need that condition to make sure each update row is mapped correctly. Replacing sku with o.sku give another error "The multi-part identifier "o..sku" could not be bound.". ANy ideas?

```
UPDATE  o
SET     sku = p.AutoSKU
FROM    o (NOLOCK)
        JOIN a (NOLOCK) ON a.Sku = o.sku
        JOIN p (NOLOCK) ON p.Code = a.ProductCode
WHERE   o.sku <> p.AutoSKU
        AND sku = a.Sku
```

Comment: Here `AND sku = a.Sku` you have to prefix the first `sku` with the appropriate table alias.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You already have the condition on `Sku` in the `on` clause.  It doesn't need to be repeated in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You are right, @GordonLinoff . I was just so concerned that the engine treat the o table in Update query differently with the o table in FROM clause. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely due to the last line - `AND sku = a.Sku` where you need to alias the first `sku` column, like below:

```
UPDATE  o
SET     sku = p.AutoSKU
FROM    o (NOLOCK)
        JOIN a (NOLOCK) ON a.Sku = o.sku
        JOIN p (NOLOCK) ON p.Code = a.ProductCode
WHERE   o.sku <> p.AutoSKU
        AND o.sku = a.Sku -- a bit redundant
```

Although as @GordonLinoff mentioned, you don't need that condition in the `WHERE` clause, since you already have it in the `ON` clause.

Comment: This one will bring error as I mentioned. I already tried it. But Gordon is correctly, I have tried it again with out that condition, and it brings correct result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine:

```
UPDATE o
    SET sku = p.AutoSKU
    FROM o JOIN
         a 
         ON a.Sku = o.sku JOIN
         p
         ON p.Code = a.ProductCode
    WHERE o.sku <> p.AutoSKU;
```

The `ON` clause already has the condition on `sku`s.  There is no need to repeat that in the `WHERE` clause.

In addition, do not use `WITH (NOLOCK)` unless you are very intentionally using it and you know what it does.

Finally, your error message suggests that you had a typo in that version of the query.  `o..sku` is not the same thing as `o.sku`.